# wp_ajax_nopriv_xxx is not firing on one site, works on all others. -1 for logged out users

Tags: ajax

my plugin uses add_action for `wp_ajax_cl_ajax` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_cl_ajax` in it's code and on the few thousand sites that are using it, it is fine but one site is not working for logged out users

a logged in user is fine, the code sends a request to ajax and everything gets returned fine.

on other blogs, a logged out user is fine but just on this one blog a -1 gets returned for the ajax request.

I have added debug code to the plugin to die at the do_ajax function with a message but it doesn't even get to that function.

here's the action for the logged out user ajax
`add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_cl_ajax','do_ajax');`

the function has this

```
function do_ajax(){
    if(isset($_REQUEST['debug'])){
      die('in ajax function');
   }
}
```

I just change the ajax url to have a var for debug (..../wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?debug=true)
on my test sites it dies, for a logged in user it dies but for a logged out user, it just returns -1 which tells me the action is not even being triggered. I added more debug code to the function that adds the actions for `has_filter` and it returns 1 so i know the action is added, just not fired.

I've tried changing the theme but no joy there

the site is using wp 3.2

does anyone have any experience with wp_ajax_nopriv_xxx not firing? what caused it for you?

as I said, it is working fine on other blogs so I know it isn't a case of a typo or missing code.

what other things can I do to determine what is causing the action not to fire?

Answer (score 1):

The condition for such hook to fire is quite simple, as per `admin-ajax.php`:

```
if ( !empty( $_REQUEST['action'] ) )
    do_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_' . $_REQUEST['action'] );
```

So the likely reasons are:

1. You script does not pass action name properly (which is unlikely if exactly same code works for logged in user).
2. Action name gets messed up in WordPress by something and it somehow depends on user being logged in.

I'd try to hook into `admin_init` and dump all of `$_REQUEST`.

Comment: I know the action is detected because the logged in user action fires for logged in users

Comment: I tried this and all vars are present and correct

Comment: @CommentLuv hmm... I am at loss then. Could you maybe share actual code? Simplified, just skeleton of what it going on.

Comment: you can see the whole thing in the commentluv plugin
wordpress.org/extend/plugins/commentluv/

it's ok, I've given up now. no errors in log and it's an isolated case . I'll give it more time if someone else reports it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that your `wp_ajax_nopriv` action isn't registered correctly. It's just declined from `admin-ajax.php`. I had a similar error with the `wp_ajax` action handler, which returned `-1` for the user role `contributer`.

The problem was that I had restricted the access to the admin backend for this user group on the `admin_init` action hook. As you can see in `admin-ajax.php` this hook will be called in the first few lines, so the request was declined there.

Maybe you have a similar problem or have activated some fancy plugins which will interfere at some point in the code.

If you could not reproduce the error, try to go through the `admin-ajax.php` file and replace step by step all `-1` return values with your own error message. Its a bit cumbersome but will let you find the reason.

Comment: thanks Roman, I think that's what I'll have to do in the future if it turns up again. Unfortunately, in this case I don't have access to the users files and now I've forgotten completely who has having the problem!